# Correct way to upload my Java Mysql application on Github

Tags: java, mysql, github

first ever question here. I'm sorry if this one has been alredy asked but I couldn't find it anywhere.
I just finished my first crud application using java and mysql, the thing is: To upload it to github I will be revealing mysql password... I mean, its a simple password and of course I have nothing more than the project data in the database. So should I find another way to upload my project or is it fairly safe to share the password?. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a public key rather than plain text password

Answer (score 0):

As a good practice, you should never store user/password in your code. There are a few alternatives to do so.

You may use variables whose values come from system variables or context files.

An even better alternative is to rely on the infrastructure, such as provided by application servers, for example.
In this case, your code looks up data sources that define the DB connection. No password, users nor even DB name, IP and port are stored in your code.

Your DB access info is stored in your infra and can be easily and securely updated without changing the code.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to thank you! I created a file with the password and the program reads it from it. I supposed that's what you meant.